# Cypress not opening in WSL2

Tags: cypress, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Following this tutorial I am trying to run Cypress in WSL2: https://shouv.medium.com/how-to-run-cypress-on-wsl2-989b83795fb6

If I run the tests so they run in my terminal (with no gui) with just `npx cypress run` then they run without error but if I try to run Cypress with the X-server by using the command `CYPRESS_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000 npx cypress open --config-file cypress.json` I get lots of errors:

````
[4735:0418/164505.014625:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
[4563:0418/164506.171450:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[4563:0418/164506.187367:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")```
````

Comment: What is inside your cypress.json file?

Comment: The latest wsl doesn't require any kind of x-server setup. It automagically launches the gui apps, including cypress without any issue.